# Can I get a char * to a std::sregex_iterator match str()

Tags: c++, regex

```
string b="some string another string";    
std::regex r("string");
std::sregex_iterator m(b.begin(),b.end(),r);

for (std::sregex_iterator end; m!=end; m++)
{
   // want a char* to m->str() in here
}
```

I'm gettng totally lost trying to determine what's what because of the templates. I've tried

```
const char *c = m->str().c_str() // compiles but points to ""
```

Answer
Pointed out by lightness below

```
const char *c = &b[m->position()]; // length of str is m->length()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const char *c = m->str().c_str()
```

`m->str()` is a temporary value, not a reference to data inside `m`, so `c` is immediately dangling.

Just store the string first:

```
const std::string str = m->str();
const char* c = str.c_str();
```

Yes, the copy is unfortunate.

---

A cheaper way than the copy would be:

```
const std::string_view sv{
   b.data() + m->position(),
   m->length()
};
```

This is great if you can use string views. **But** it is not null-terminated! So, if you really do need a `const char*`, this won't work for you and you're pretty much stuck with a fresh buffer.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I only looked at the sregex_iterator because the easier to work with smatch seemed to involve a lot of copying.

Comment: @NoComprende You may be able to use `m->length()` and `m->position()` instead to index into the original string, instead of using `m->str()`. See my updated answer for a bit more on that.

Comment: That's it Lightness. c=&b[m->position()]. Many thanks.

Comment: @NoComprende As I said, that's not null terminated at the end of the match, so it's not the same thing. That's why I didn't give that solution.